# Fabricjs crop/replace part of background image with white

Tags: javascript, angular, image, canvas, fabricjs

I need to load an image as canvas, cut it in half, and replace the cut part with white background color.

There are **4 possibilities**:

*(Yellow color = remaining image, white color = white background)

[image]

**First two possibilities**: The image is cut **vertically** and we keep the **left part** **OR** the **right part** (switch white and yellow color in the image above) of the image. The other part become a white background.

[image]

**Other two possibilities**: The image is cut **horizontally** and we keep the **top part** **OR** the **bottom part** (switch white and yellow color in the image above) of the image. The other part become a white background.

---

What I've tried:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, img => {
    this.canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas), {
        left: img.getScaledWidth()/2,
        originX: 'left'
    });

    this.canvas.setWidth(img.getScaledWidth());
    this.canvas.setHeight(img.getScaledHeight());
    this.canvas.renderAll();
}, { crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' });
```

Two problems:

- The remaining image is in the wrong side
- The other part is transparent instead of a white background

---

**Is it possible to reach that with Fabricjs ?** (*Otherwise how can I do ?*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of *@Raman* here is a solution:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, img => {
    let rect;

    // Remaining image = right
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: img.getScaledWidth() / 2,
        height: img.getScaledHeight(),
        fill: 'white'
    });

    // Remaining image = left
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: img.getScaledWidth() / 2,
        height: img.getScaledHeight(),
        fill: 'white',
        left: img.getScaledWidth() / 2
    });

    // Remaining image = bottom
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: img.getScaledWidth(),
        height: img.getScaledHeight() / 2,
        fill: 'white'
    });

    // Remaining image = top
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: img.getScaledWidth(),
        height: img.getScaledHeight(),
        fill: 'white',
        top: img.getScaledHeight() / 2
    });

    const group = new fabric.Group([img, rect]);

    this.canvas.setBackgroundImage(group);

    this.canvas.setWidth(img.getScaledWidth());
    this.canvas.setHeight(img.getScaledHeight());
    this.canvas.renderAll();
}, { crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a grouping of canvas elements for that. I've created an example, you can see it here

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-curran-bkwtk?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you it helped. I posted a complete solution.